# My Android WebView application shows error, works good on the browser(Chrome)

Tags: android, webview

```
mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings settings=mWebView.getSettings();
    //webview setting
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");

    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    settings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new webChromeClient(this));

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
```

and everything works fine on my web. But when I try to login to the web, it shows error page.

[SOLVED]
It was simply web page error. Web developer has solved the issue.

Comment: post your WebAppInterface (login part). Anyway it seems to have error in server side. (MobileLoginController)

Comment: Yes, it was server side error. Thanks dude!